# How to migrate sns and sqs using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

In my aws account, there is having a 250+ SNS and SQS i need to migrate one region to another region using cloudformation, any one can help to write a script using yaml

```
Resources:
  T1:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Topic'
    Properties: {}

  Q1:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
    Properties: {}

  Q1P:
    Type: 'AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy'
    Properties:
      Queues:
        - !Ref Q1
      PolicyDocument:
        Id: AllowIncomingAccess
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Ref AWS::AccountId
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
              - sqs:ReceiveMessage
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt Q1.Arn
          -
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Action:
              - sqs:SendMessage
            Resource:
              - !GetAtt Q1.Arn

  T1SUB:
    Type: 'AWS::SNS::Subscription'
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      Endpoint: !GetAtt Q1.Arn
      TopicArn: !Ref T1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Former2](https://former2.com/) which is an open-sourced tool to:

> Former2 allows you to **generate Infrastructure-as-Code outputs from your existing resources** within your AWS account. By making the relevant calls using the AWS JavaScript SDK, Former2 will scan across your infrastructure and present you with the list of resources for you to choose which to generate outputs for.